# empty() , isset() not working to check if a variable has data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, isset, is-empty

```
$mobile_no = LoginModel::where(['mobile_no' => $request->mobile_no])->get(['mobile_no']);
 dd($mobile_no);
 if(!empty( $mobile_no )){
     $request->session()->put('error','This mobile no. Already Exist!');
     return view::make('errors.503'); 
}
```

I used `if(isset($mobile_no))` also still redirecting to `error page` while `$mobile_no` is empty.

I checked variable using `dd($mobile_no)` and showing this output 
`Collection {#188 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method always returns a collection. Therefore you need to use `first()` or just use `count()` for easy comparison.

```
$result = LoginModel::where('mobile_no', $request->mobile_no)->count();

if($result) {
    $request->session()->put('error','This mobile no. Already Exist!');
    return view::make('errors.503');
}
```

You could also use the validator to check for unique mobile number and throw errors. You can read about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique